# Right class to wrap many dynamically generated images in android?

Tags: android, image, dynamic, canvas

There seems to be a lot of classes, which provide a surface to draw on:

- View
- Bitmap
- Drawable
- SurfaceView

My application generates many pictures dynamically, by using vector graphics.
What is the right class to use, if my aim is to save the pictures, so that they are ready to be drawn into an ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html), in the first paragraph:
- use Views for drawing static items
- use SurfaceView for dynamic and  performance sensitive apps, like games